# How to add shadow with UIImageView resizableImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

How to add shadow with resizableImageView[image]

```
imgViewBubble.image = bubbleImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets:
            UIEdgeInsetsMake(17, 21, 17, 21),resizingMode: .stretch).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

Comment: At least take time to write the reason for vote down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imgViewBubble.clipsToBounds = false 
imgViewBubble.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
imgViewBubble.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
imgViewBubble.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
imgViewBubble.layer.shadowRadius = 5
```